# How to remove the footer record from the CSV file while loading into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to load a csv file from GCS to BigQuery without the header and the footer record.

I am having difficulty of removing the footer from loading into the BigQuery

In the Google docs, its says about the header row and the way to skip it, but not about the footer row

For Header row I will be using

```
   job_config=bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
   job_config.skip_leading_rows=1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the BigQuery API does not include this feature, you could open a [Feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_for_or_create_bugs_and_feature_requests_by_product) for that.

From your code, I understand that you are using `python`, as a workaround to skip the footer row:

1. Read the `csv` file from GCS using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
2. Remove the last row:

```py
df.drop(df.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
```

3. Load it to BigQuery, skipping the Header Row.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that worked for you! Would be great if you could accept the answer, so the upcoming developers will check this solution also.